# one list to two lists in scheme

Tags: scheme

i have a list `((x 1) (y 2) (z 3))` and I want to make 2 seprate lists: `(x y z)` and 
`(1 2 3)`

I tried using recursive call, using car and cdr, but it didnt work. there is a simple way to do it?
Thanks.

Comment: It is better to post the code that you tried, so we can get a better idea of what went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cdr` returns the tail of the list, which is a list (assuming the input is a list, and not a cons cell).  You probably want to use `cadr` instead (short-hand for `(car (cdr foo))`).  You could do:

```
(map car lst)  ; '(x y z)
(map cadr lst) ; '(1 2 3)
```

(`map` will call apply the given function to each item in the list).

Answer (score 1):

```
(apply map list lst) ; returns ((x y z) (1 2 3))
```

Or use `unzip2` from srfi-1.

Answer (score 0):

with ls as your list: (map car ls) and (map car (map cdr ls))